# Guidelines regarding TIBCO EMS session management

Tags: performance, session, jms, tibco, ems

there are frequently complaints about poor performance for one of our EMS servers.

I have noticed that there are typically many more open sessions than there are consumers+producers.

For example, right now there are 4310 open sessions, 1728 consumers and 1421 producers.

Could this be an issue or this nothing to worry about?

Thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by poor performance

Comment: Slow response times, getting a connection to the server is slow.

Comment: And what does the resource monitoring on the server tell you?

Comment: Resource monitoring in what sense?

Comment: CPU, Memory, Disk IO, Network IO, etc. i.e. is the EMS daemon resource bound and if so, on which resource?

Comment: CPU usage is rather high, other metrics you mentioned looks ok. Not sure what you mean with this _"is the EMS daemon resource bound and if so, on which resource?"_

Comment: OK, so if the CPU usage is high, then the EMS daemon might be CPU bound (i.e. the performance of EMS is bounded/limited by the amount of CPU it can get on the server). Is the EMS daemon creating the high CPU usage or something else?

Comment: It is the process **tibemsd64** that is consuming **lots of CPU**. Currently there are 1537 connections, 9959 sessions, 5750 producers and 1551 consumers.  Message Memory usage is only 18MB out of 2GB. Fsync for Sync Storage is disabled, whatever that means.